# Is there a way to reliably check that systemd supports --user?

Tags: linux, ansible, systemd, dbus

I'm trying to set up some user services using Ansible and systemd.

On Ubuntu and RHEL 7 I'm getting

```
# systemctl --user status
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused
```

For Ubuntu I clarified the error, it's because of this:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html

> run systemctl within a given service manager scope, either as the default system scope (system), the current user's scope (user), or the scope of all users (global).
>   For systemd to work with 'user', the executing user must have its own instance of dbus started (systemd requirement). The user dbus process is normally started during normal login, but not during the run of Ansible tasks. Otherwise you will probably get a 'Failed to connect to bus: no such file or directory' error.

Basically DBus needs to be started before `systemd --user` can work. I'm not sure how to do that either, but I can work around it in other ways, I think.

However, the main blocker right now is: how do I check, generically, for the availability of the functionality?

I tried `systemctl show` and there's no explicit "user" feature. Is the flag the "+PAM" from the `Features` line? I know that systemd uses PAM at least partially to implement it, I don't know if it's needed for other features.

How can I check that "my" systemd supports `--user` in a reliable manner? Is there a file I could check? A command? Something else? DBus voodoo?

Answer (score 5):

It's not a matter of whether systemd *supports* `--user` (all reasonably recent versions do), but rather whether (a) a user session is currently running, and (b) your Ansible process can connect to it.

A solution for both problems is `become_method: machinectl` (see [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#may-not-access-environment-variables-populated-by-pamd-systemd)), but it [has issues](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/56571) on some systemd versions.

---

If that method doesn't work for you, there are workarounds. Typically an Ansible session does not create a user systemd instance; you need to log in locally for that to happen. However, you can [enable lingering](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances) to always have a systemd for that user.

The second problem is connecting to that instance. This needs the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable to be set; typically to `/run/user/<UID>`. It's not set by the usual `become_method: sudo`, but you can use something along these lines to figure it out and pass it to the `systemd` task:

```
- name: "Find uid of user"
  command: "id -u {{ the_user }}"
  register: the_user_uid
  check_mode: no # Run even in check mode, otherwise the playbook fails with --check.
  changed_when: false

- name: "Determine XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
  set_fact:
    xdg_runtime_dir: "/run/user/{{ the_user_uid.stdout }}"
  changed_when: false

- name: "Enable some service"
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ the_user }}"
  environment:
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: "{{ xdg_runtime_dir }}"
  systemd:
    scope: user
    daemon_reload: yes
    name: the_service.service
    enabled: yes
    state: started
```

Comment: The workaround worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: In the second taks there is typo in `the_user_id` should be `the_user_uid`